# why the return value is nil and shows error?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdictionary

```
func fetchDataForSQL(query : String)->NSDictionary{

    let url = URL(string: "###############################################")
    var jsonDBdata: NSDictionary!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = query.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error!)

        }
        else {
             jsonDBdata = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            print(jsonDBdata)
        }
    }.resume()

 return jsonDBdata
}
```

Here if I print the `jsonDBdata` inside else part it is printing the value but when I return it, it shows the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Why can't I return here? What is its scope?

Comment: You are missing the async concept. `print(jsonDBdata)` will be called AFTER `return jsonDBdata`. Look for "Swift + Asynchrone + Closure" to find solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to return the value `jsonDBdata` whose value you get from inside the completion of a block. So you need to convert the function to return value in block/closure. You could modify as

```
func fetchDataForSQL(query : String,sucess:((NSDictionary) -> Void)?,failure:((Error?) -> Void)?){

    let url = URL(string: "###############################################")
    var jsonDBdata: NSDictionary!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = query.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error!)
            failure!(error)
        }
        else {
             jsonDBdata = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            print(jsonDBdata)
            sucess!(jsonDBdata)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: wat are the other two parameter...can u explain me....what should i pass in it...

Comment: They are closures/block which here in this case we pass as function arguments. Here when the task completes either the success or the failure will be passed whether the task completed successfully or with error. You may refer to http://hayageek.com/swift-blocks-tutorial/  for detailed description on closures/blocks

Comment: thanks dude...i understood how closures work...in that code the return type in NSDictionary pls do edit it and its working fine...

Comment: Ohh I just missed it.

Comment: @selvabalasubramanian if its working fine, it would be great if you could accept this answer so that it would be helpful for somebody else too.

Comment: i am now clear with closures but is there any way to return the value...like we do in other languages..

Comment: Thanks man
Here the thing is you are trying to return a variable which will get value once the asynchronous task gets completed. So you can either use blocks like this or fire a notification on the completion of the task.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of declaration, `jsonDBdata` is nil. You are performing the task by `URLSession.shared.dataTask` using blocks, but you are returning the `jsonDBdata` immediately. While your task is executing, you have returned the jsonDBdata(which is nil).

So write `return jsonDBdata` in else condition and return empty jsonDBdata in error case.

Comment: i tried but i shows error  "unexpected non-void return in void function"

Comment: Initialise you NSDictionary as follows:- `var jsonDBdata : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()`

Comment: i tried but it shows thee same error  "unexpected non-void return in void function"